# each time after sudo apt-get install process this little failure-message?

Tags: apt

here is sudo apt-get install  ending now with:

> Trigger for initramfs-tools are processing ...
>
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic

... then here comes this:

> failure while processing:
>
> postfix
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

what shall I do to iron this in 12.10 ?

Answer (score 0):

First try running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postfix
```

This will completely uninstall the postfix package.  If this does not fix your problem, try running the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

These commands will attempt to fix any broken packages on your system.